# Build Run Concept

Tags: java, api, versionone

I'm working with the VersionOne Java Api to amend different attributes of stories. But I want to integrate VersionOne with my Continuous Integration environment. I've read up a little on BuildRuns but I don't see much in the API of how you are to create a buildrun then assign it to a story. Could someone give a brief idea on what a buildrun is suppose to accomplish and if/how to create it using the Java API. A code example would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A BuildRun represents a build of the project that you are working on, and it includes information about the BuildProject it is related to, the ChangeSets it contains, and the Stories and Defects (PrimaryWorkitems) that are addressed in it.

In addition, BuildRuns are part of an asset hierarchy:

- Projects have BuildProjects
- BuildProjects have BuildRuns
- BuildRuns have ChangeSets

You can see the attributes of the BuildRun asset with this VersionOne Meta API query:

```
http://{server}/{instance}/meta.v1/BuildRun?xsl=api.xsl
```

As you will see in the meta, required attributes for a BuildRun are a BuildProject, a date, and a name. This means that before you can create a BuildRun, you must first create a BuildProject to associate it with.

Assuming that you already have a BuildProject, you can issue an HTTP POST to create a BuildRun like this:

URL:

```
http://{server}/{instance}/rest-1.v1/Data/BuildRun
```

XML PAYLOAD:

```
<Asset>
    <Attribute name="BuildProject" act="set">BuildProject:4049</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Name" act="set">My New BuildRun</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Date" act="set">12/17/2014</Attribute>
</Asset>
```

Alternatively, using the Java SDK it would look like this:

```
public static void createBuildRun() throws V1Exception {

   V1APIConnector _dataConnector = new V1APIConnector("http://{server}/{instance}/rest-1.v1/", "username", "password");
   V1APIConnector _metaConnector = new V1APIConnector("http://{server}/{instance}/meta.v1/");

   IMetaModel _metaModel = new MetaModel(_metaConnector);
   IServices _services = new Services(_metaModel, _dataConnector);

   Oid buildProjectId = Oid.fromToken("BuildProject:4049", _metaModel);
   IAssetType assetType = _metaModel.getAssetType("BuildRun");
   Asset newAsset = _services.createNew(assetType, buildProjectId);
   IAttributeDefinition nameAttribute = assetType.getAttributeDefinition("Name");
   IAttributeDefinition dateAttribute = assetType.getAttributeDefinition("Date");
   newAsset.setAttributeValue(nameAttribute, "My New BuildRun");
   newAsset.setAttributeValue(dateAttribute, new Date("12/17/2014"));
   _services.save(newAsset);
}
```